# Mustache template with different states

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, mustache, hogan.js

I have a status flag on my model which can take one of four values: active, inactive, processing or uploading.

In a mustache template I want to switch on and off different parts of the template depending on which value the status flag is. Is there a decent way to do this?

I don't really want to have 4 different templates-one for each state.

I tried using an isActive, isProcessing etc method on the model which returns `this.get('status') === 'active'`, but as its a function it won't be passed into the template.

Comment: You should definitely be able to show part of a template based on the  return value of `isActive` by using `{{#isActive}} this content is only shown if isActive() returns a truthy value {{/isActive}}`.

Comment: You cant have functions in plain JSON, so like the answer below says you need to represent the values with attributes by intercepting the toJSON call

Comment: Well, you didn't mention you were passing JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the usual approach is convert your model to a simple blob of data with [`toJSON`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-toJSON) and then hand the blob of data to your Mustache template. So, all you need to do is provide your own `toJSON` that includes your method calls as attributes. For example:

```
toJSON: function() {
    var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
    json.isActive     = this.isActive();
    json.isProcessing = this.isProcessing();
    return json;
}
```

Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/22aYH/

Then, you can have things like this in your template:

```
{{#isActive}}It is active!{{/isActive}}
{{#isProcessing}}Be patient, we're working on it...{{/isProcessing}}
```